# Can a separable differential equation be both linear and nonlinear

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm quite confused if this separable differential equation is linear or not:

$(x-2y)dx-(8x^2-9)dy=0$

From what I understood, a differential equation is nonlinear if:

1. The dependent variable is multiplied to its derivative
2. A derivative has an exponent greater than 1

Thus, in this given example, you can rearrange it in two ways, first in terms of dy/dx:

$(x-2y)=(8x^2-9)\frac{dy}{dx}$

Which is linear, however, when expressed as dx/dy:

$(x-2y)\frac{dx}{dy}=(8x^2-9)$

It no longer is, since $\frac{dx}{dy}$ is multiplied with x.

So, what's the verdict, really? Is it nonlinear or linear? Or should it just be specified in what terms it becomes linear, and when it does not.

Comment: Why do you call it a **separable** equation? Looks nonseparable to me. How would you separate the variables?

Comment: It's linear in $y$ and $dy/dx$, nonlinear in $x$ and $dx/dy$. The "differential form" $Mdx+Ndy=0$ is neutral or ambiguous as to which is the independent and which is the dependent variable.

Answer (score 0):

$(x-2y)~dx-(8x^2-9)~dy=0$

$(x-2y)~dx=(8x^2-9)~dy$

$(8x^2-9)\dfrac{dy}{dx}=x-2y$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}+\dfrac{2y}{8x^2-9}=\dfrac{x}{8x^2-9}$

This is a first-order linear ODE.

Of course follow the simplest properties.

Comment: The OP knows that. He's confused about the terminology in view of the fact that the equation is linear if $x$ is the independent variable but nonlinear if $y$ is the independent variable.

Comment: Ohh, right I can do that. That means, for dx/dy: 

$(x-2y)dx=(8x^2-9)dy$ =>

$(x-2y)\frac{dx}{dy}=(8x^2-9)$ =>

$\frac{dx}{dy}-\frac{8x^2}{x-2y}+\frac{9}{x-2y}=0$;

So this should be linear, then?